# Authenticate enduser without disturbing the django admin site

Tags: python, django, django-models

first, i login to django admin site, then i go to the login page in my html template and i logout, but when i go again to django admin site, the django admin site is also logged out. How do I separate these two things, so that when the enduser login and logout it doesn't affect the django admin?

my project uses custom user model, that's all nothing else.

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, first_name, middle_name, last_name, club_favorite, email, password=None):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a username")
        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            first_name = first_name,
            middle_name = middle_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            club_favorite = club_favorite,
            email = email,
        )
        
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, username, first_name, middle_name, last_name, club_favorite, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            password = password,
            first_name = first_name,
            middle_name = middle_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            club_favorite = club_favorite,
            email = email,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class MyAccount(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    club_favorite = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    object = MyAccountManager()
    
    USERNAME_FIELD =    'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'club_favorite', 'email']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True
    
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
    
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

Need sulution ...........................................

Answer (score 0):

a) You can use different browsers for user and admin sessions

b) You can use browser in a private mode mode

Comment: thank you. but i am not looking for that way. you should suggest me to add something in my project, in my code

Comment: this is not possible, this how web apps and http sessions work.

Comment: you most likely would need to implement two separate sessions for the django admin vs. your other pages, I suggest digging through the django codebase to see how this would be possible https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name